# Docker on Windows: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /app/wiki.de.bin: no space left on device

Tags: windows, docker

I am trying to add a `.bin` file (name `wiki.de.bin`) to the docker via a DockerFile. When I try to build it, I get an error message:

```
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /app/wiki.de.bin: no space left on device.
```

I have done `docker system prune` as well as `docker volume ls -qf dangling=true`, however it does not help.

What should I do?

I am using Windows 10 Home which has Hyper-V available.

Here is the relevant System information.

[image]

Does it have anything to do with the fact that I have only 6.42GB available virtual memory? IF yes, how do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also tried docker volume prune ?
Sometimes I have to do this and then regenerate my volumes later.

Comment: No, I did not try that. How shall I regenerate the volumes later? Can you care to please explain in a little more detail, please?

Comment: It will generate them when you build your image and start your container